# Irreducible decomposition of variety of tuples of product-zero matrices

Tags: matrices, algebraic-geometry

Let's call matrices $A$ and $B$ mutually orthogonal if $AB=BA=0$.
The set of mutually orthogonal $2\times 2$ matrices is an affine algebraic variety over any field defined by $AB=0, BA=0$ in $\operatorname{Mat}^2_{2\times 2}(k)$. According to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/274658/variety-of-pairs-of-product-zero-matrices) given variety has three irreducible components $X_i=\{(A,B)\vert AB=BA=0, \operatorname{rank} A \leq i, \operatorname{rank} B \leq n-i\}$. I think I don't understand properly why $X_1$ is irreducible. Need some help here. After all i think that this decomposition works over  any field.

My main question is about the set of pairs of $2\times 2$ matrices connected with at most one non-zero matrix i.e. $\{(A,B)\vert \exists C\neq0: AC=CA=0, BC=CB=0 \}$. Matrices $A$ and $B$ are not forbidden to be mutually orthogonal. (We can say that "distance" between $A$ and $B$ less than 3)
This set is an algebraic variety over any field.
Given that $C$ is nonzero and singular, we obtain that $\operatorname{rank}C=1$, hence $\operatorname{rank} A \leq 1, \operatorname{rank} B \leq 1$. I think, that this variety should be irreducible over any field for the same reason, but i have no idea how to prove it.

My attempt was to take projection from triples $(A,C,B)$ to C. Let $\Omega_2$ be the set of $2\times 2$ singular matrices. Than $\dim\Omega_2=3$ and $\pi:\Omega_2\times\Omega_2\times\Omega_2\longrightarrow\Omega_2$ is surjective map. We can bring C to Jordan normal form:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda& 0\\
0& 0\\
\end{pmatrix}
\quad\text{or}\quad
\begin{pmatrix}
0& 1\\
0& 0\\
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Suppose $C$ is of the first form, than:
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
0& 0\\
0& a\\
\end{pmatrix}
\quad\quad
B = \begin{pmatrix}
0& 0\\
0& b\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
The fibers over dense open set of rank 1 matrices in $\Omega_2$ has dimension 3 (We can freely choose $\lambda, a, b)$. Than by Fiber dimension theorem, dimension of our set of triples equals $3+3=6$. I haven't thought of any further proof yet.